# Sum multiple keys of hash in one line

Tags: perl, hash

I need to sum differents keys of the hash in one line instead of using foreach.

If i have a hash:

```
%a = (
 a => 4,
 b => 3,
 c => 7,
 d => 2,
 e => 4
);
```

For example:
$a{a d e} 
output: 10

It could be possible or I need a foreach??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible with hash slice notation

```
use List::Utils 'sum';
$the_sum = sum( @a{"a","d","e"} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $sum = 0;
$sum += $_ for @a{qw( a d e )};

print $sum, "\n";
```